# Visual C++ call method from other class

Tags: c++, class, methods, call

There is class Road with its Road.h and Road.cpp which contains implementation of method isInside(int x, int y) and the road rectangle sizes. And there is class Car with its .h and .cpp and it contains int x and int y. How can I from Car::move() method check if the car is inside the Road?

```
Car::move()
{
  bool isIn = // isInside(x,y) How to do this? It is in another class
}
```

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question.  What is `isInside`?  How does the car know which road its associated with (or vice versa)?

Comment: But let's start at the beginning. You do have an object of class Road, yes?

Comment: isInside() is a method that checks if x,y coordinates are inside the road rectangle. And it returns true/false.
I have object road = new Road(pictureBox1);
and I have a car object too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the method `isInside` a static method in the `Road` class, then you will call it using the class scope operator - something like this `Road::isInside(x,y);`. If, in the `Car` class you have an object of the `Road` class, then based on whether it is an object or a pointer, you can call it as `roadObject.isInside(x,y);` or `roadObjectPointer->isInside(x,y);`